# Nagios change threshold values

Tags: nagios, smart, check-mk

I'm using nagios checkmk 1.2.2 to monitor some hosts.

How can I adjust specific smart values per host so they won't create a critical alert?

For example:
CRIT - Reallocated sectors: 2CRIT

I only want a critical alert if the reallocated sector counts goes over 10 on this specific host and over 20 on host B.

I went through the menus but I can't find anything for overriding these values.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can edit check parameters in check_mk by creating a rule for the service. By creating a rule can overwrite the default values for a service.
If you are using WATO you can get to the rule creation dialog by clicking on the third icon from the right in the service overview screen. The icon looks like this:  [image: The icon looks like this]

In the following dialog you can either set "no level" and check_mk will always return OK for the service or change the fixed values.